# Do custom post type children inherit parent's taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress

The title says it all... I have some custom posts setup with a parent, child, grand-child and great grand-children. If I assign the parent with a taxonomy, do all of the children, grand-child and great grand-children inherit that same taxonomy? Or, do I need to assign that taxonomy to each child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to a taxonomy term instead of a taxonomy.

If so, the answer is: No, the children, grand-children, great-grand-children etc. don't inherit the same term.

So you have to assign that term to each child specifically.